# It seems inconsistent the ways tensorflow allows me to specify variable length dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, dimension

I'm a novice to tensorflow. I was practicing coding with this [tutorial code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py). Most of all the code made sense to me but at some points I got stuck.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
```

With `tf.placholder` function I had to specify variable length dimesion with `None`. But with `tf.reshape` I had to use `-1`, not `None`. In documentation for the two functions, both of the pertaining arguments have the name `shape`. So I am feeling lost here. Do they really have different meanings? Or is it just a small design mistake of the tensorflow developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand it this way: in a placeholder the value "None" indicates: "could be any value". Like in your case: you have a batch size that can be anything. 
In a reshape function, -1 indicates "whatever value is remaining to make this shape work". In you case, your x gets the shape (batch*n_steps), as this is the shape x needs to be to fit the same data in a matrix.

Interesting note: you CAN use multiple None values in a placeholder (to indicate any batch size, any width and height of an image)... But you can't use multiple -1 values in a reshape function!